# Display query result as resultset header

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below data,

[image]

I would like to show the same as,

[image]

I have tried the below query,

```
select 
CASE Name
        WHEN 'DAC' THEN value
    END AS DAC,
    CASE Name
        WHEN 'SAC' THEN value
    END AS SAC
FROM 
 table
```

The query gives me the below result,

[image]

What should my query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use conditional aggregation

```
select id,
       max(CASE Name WHEN 'DAC' THEN value END) AS DAC,
       max(CASE Name WHEN 'SAC' THEN value END) AS SAC
FROM table
group by id
```